# Need menu to close when anything other than a link is clicked (including the menu icon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

http://emperor.graphics/

As you'll probably be able to tell by my JavaScript, I am no expert. I cobbled this together from multiple sources and it mostly works, but there are two frustrations I'm having:

1. On mobile, the menu does not always close when you tap outside it.
2. Clicking the menu icon itself does not close the menu.

   ```
   $(function() {
     $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
       $(this).next('.dropdown').addClass("nav-open");
     });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var target = e.target;
      if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && 
       !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
         $('.dropdown').removeClass("nav-open");
      }
    });
   });
   ```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
$(function() {
    var toggle = ".dropdown-toggle";
    $(toggle).on("click", function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').toggleClass("nav-open");
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
       var target = $(e.target);
       if (!target.is(toggle) && !target.parent().is(toggle)) {
           $(".dropdown").removeClass("nav-open");
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted, but I actually think it works quite nicely now that I've added a second state to the menu icon—clicking the icon now closes the menu. On mobile, tapping outside of the menu is tricky anyway as you can easily tap on a link you didn't mean to visit. Thanks for your help!